# Emptying specific cells in the same row of an amended cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am relatively new to VBA.

Below is my code that works on just row 2.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public precedent

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.[D2]) Is Nothing Then
            If Me.precedent <> Me.[D2].Value Then
               Me.[F2] = ""
               Me.[H2] = ""
               Me.precedent = Me.[D2].Value
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I would like this code to run on every row except row 1 as this is my header.

How do I do this? Would I use a loop?

Comment: No, a loop isn't a solution. Just check the column index of `Target`. If it's 4, then delete F and H.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be so complicated. Just check `Target.Row` and `Target.Column`. If the former is greater than `1` and the latter is equal to `4`, trigger whatever action you want.

Modify the following code accordingly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column = 4 Then
        Range("F" & Target.Row) = vbNullString
        Range("H" & Target.Row) = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't have to use a loop.  Since you want to omit the first row, you should set a range that you want this code to fire when it is modified.  Currently, you are checking it against D2 only.  When your `If` statement is checking for your entire range, you can then use `Target` as the specific cell that was changed (instead of using D2.)

Here's some code that should do what you want:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rangeToCheck As Range
rangeToCheck = Range(Cells(2,4),Cells(Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count,4)) 'If your range isn't dynamic, you could put static numbers here
    If Not Intersect(Target, rangeToCheck) Is Nothing Then 'Now checks against all of Column D, omitting Row 1
        If Target.precedent <> Target.Value Then
           Target.Offset(0,2).Value = "" 'Clear Column F in Target Row
           Target.Offset(0,4).Value = "" 'Clear Column H in Target Row
           Target.precedent = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code that will skip row 1.  Note the .Row and .Column properties of 'Target'

```
Option Explicit

Public precedent
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Debug.Print Target.Column
Debug.Print Target.Row
    If Target.Row <> 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.[D2]) Is Nothing Then
            If Me.precedent <> Me.[D2].Value Then
               Me.[F2] = ""
               Me.[H2] = ""
               Me.precedent = Me.[D2].Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this one:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub

    If Me.Cells(Target.Row, 4) = "" Then
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 6) = ""
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, 8) = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will clear Column D which he did not want to do and will not omit Row 1, which was a requirement.